# Function sorting array of structures by passed structure member

Tags: c

here is my problem:
let's say I have a struct:

```
enum color{Black, Red, White};
struct car
{   int weight;
    int price;
    enum color my_color;
};
```

I've initialized 10 element array:

```
struct car cars[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cars[i].weight = (rand() % 1000); // do not mind the number values
        cars[i].price= (rand() % 1000);
        cars[i].my_color= (rand() % 2);
    }
```

Now my job is to write a function which would return sorted array, and the passed argument should be either of struct members (weight, price, color). I know there are lot of sorting algorithms but I have no idea how to sort it using only one of the members. How would this sorting function look like?

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

In C, there is no way to syntactically access a struct member as such in order to have some generic comparison on them. That being said, the usual approach would be to call the `qsort` library function, which is introduced [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm), to perform the sorting. It is designed to take a function pointer as an agrument; this would be used to implement and provide a function which does that actual comparison.

To solve the task in the question, It would be necessary to implement a comparison function for each member of the `car` type.